# Decay rate of fourier coefficients of function which has a jump discontinuity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, continuity

I have read this statement in a lecturer notes of Fourier analysis:
"If a function has a jump discontinuity, then its Fourier coefficients decay like $ \frac{1}{n} $."
But, I have not been able to prove it.
Could someone provide an explanation to verify this statement.
Thank you.

Comment: The statement cannot possibly be correct. Are you sure it doesn't say that the Fourier coefficients decay **no faster than** $1/n$? There exists continuous functions whose Fourier coefficients decay arbitrarily slowly. Add one such function to your favorite function with jump discontinuity and you have one which decays slower than $1/n$.

Comment: Are does "function" always mean "piecewise smooth" in your context?

Comment: Yes. In my context, "function" always mean "piecewise  smooth".

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a $1$-periodic piecewise $C^1$ function with finitely many jump discontinuites at $a_l$ of height $b_l$ then integrating by parts $$c_n(f)=\int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2i\pi nx}dx$$ gives 
$$c_n(f) = \frac{c_n(f')}{2i\pi n}+\frac{\sum_{l=1}^L b_l e^{2i\pi a_l n}}{2i\pi n}$$ where $f'$ is the piecewise continuous $1$-periodic function obtained by differentiating $f$ away from the discontinuities, since $f'\in L^2$ then $\sum_n |c_n(f')|^2=\|f'\|_{L^2[0,1]}^2$ implies that $c_n(f')\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you give me a explanation for case of $ f $ is a $1$-periodic piecewise continuous function.

Comment: If $f$ is only (piecewise) continuous then its Fourier coefficients don't have to decay in $O(1/n)$

Comment: How to distinguish piecewise continuous function and piecewise $ C^1 $ function? Whether both of them might have finitely many jump discontinuites?

Comment: ?? Check if it extends to a  $C^1$ or only $C^0$ function on each $[a_l,a_{l+1}]$